# aptitude: list all previous recommended packages

Tags: debian, aptitude, packages

Sometimes when installing a package, aptitude recommends several other packages.

Is there a way to show all previous recommended packages of all installed packages?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the replys so far. I already tried:

```
aptitude show ~i | grep '^Recommends' | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

Thats mostly ok. But it gives also things back like:

```
 console-setup | console-data (>= 2002.12.04dbs-1)
```

I want an easy way, to install all missing recommended packages.

So

```
 aptitude install console-setup | console-data (>= 2002.12.04dbs-1)
```

won't work ;-)

Is there a way, without manual checking all entries, to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Synaptic -> Custom Filters -> Missing Recommends

or

aptitude search '~RBrecommends:~i'

(thanks to http://blog.isonoe.net/post/2011/07/18/Debian-Tips-1%3A-Find-missing-recommended-packages)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there's a more elegant way, but this works for me,

```
for package in $(dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | awk '{print $1}')
  do
    echo $package
    dpkg-query -s $package | grep Recommends
  done
```

Answer (score 2):

another suggestion:

```
awk '/(^Package|^Recomm)/' /var/lib/dpkg/status | grep -B1 ^Recommends
```

@EightBitTony: awk is also very good in searching, try this:

```
dpkg --get-selections | awk ' !/deinstall$/{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here my way - report for missing recommends :)

```
apt-cache --no-pre-depends --no-depends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances depends `dpkg --get-selections | grep '\sinstall$' | cut -f1` | grep -vf <(dpkg --get-selections | grep '\sinstall$' | cut -f1 | sed -e 's/^/ /' -e 's/\(:.*\|\)$/$/') | grep -B1 '^ '
```

Answer (score 2):

Get a list of installed packages with missing recommended package:

`aptitude search '?installed?broken-recommends'`

Get a list of not installed, missing packages that are recommended by installed packages - "missing recommends":

`aptitude search '?broken-reverse-recommends(?installed)'`

Get which package is recommending a specific "missing recommend":

`aptitude search '?installed?broken-recommends(MISSING_PKG_NAME)'`

One liner: For all "missing recommends", get by which packages are recommended:

`for p in $(aptitude search -F%p '?broken-reverse-recommends(?installed)'); do echo $p; aptitude search "?installed?broken-recommends($p)"; done`

You can find "missing recommends" in Synaptic package manager. (As I see, Synaptic shows also the missing Suggested packages.)

You can install all "missing recommends" with one command but I do not recommend it! First, review the list of packages before install.
(For example, fresh install of debian buster shows missing "default-mta", which is a virtual package.)

`apt install $(aptitude search -F%p '?broken-reverse-recommends(?installed)')`

(This is summary from few similar questions. Hope it will help someone else.)